# How to create sandbox in trial version?

Tags: sandbox

I am new to salesforce.  I am trying to create a developer edition sandbox on SFDC. But unable to see Sandbox option under data management in SetUp tab.
I have registered free trial version both for professional and developer edition.

Answer (score 1):

sandboxes wont be available in developer editions...You should have licensed instanse to create sandboxes..  you can create sandboxes in Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Database.com Editions only